# Retrieve all children element tag with a specific class from a div element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following DOM tree:

```
<div class="myclass">
     <td>
           // lots of td and tr elementds...
      </td>
      <div>
           // lots of td and tr and div elementds...
           .....
           .....
           <span class="myspan">
              // lots of td and tr and div elementds...
              .....
              .....
           </span>           
      </div>
</div>
```

I have several main div element - the div with class="myclass"

I have the follwing code:

```
  $("div").each(function(i,e) {
    if ($(e).hasClass("myclass")) {

        // up to here i have all the div with myclass
             .....
             .....
           //code should be added here
    }
  })
```

how can retrieve all the span elements with the class myspan - which are inside the main div element  using JQuery?

I want to be more clear:
what I need is a list of elements which has the class = myspan and located under the current div element , The code should be added in the place I wrote
because each div element will have a different set of elements.

I hope i make my self clear now.
please help,
Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should do that for you.

```
$("div.myclass span.myspan").each(function() {
    console.log(this);
});
```

**Edit**

An alternate way to do this, where the parent context is kept is shown in the code below. This update was based on the comments to this answer. I've left the original answer (above), as the way the original question was worded, it may be useful to others who stumble across this answer.

```
$("div.myclass").each(function(i) {
    console.log("spans within div index " + i);
    $(this).find(".myspan").each(function() {
        console.log(this);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ryanbrill/Q4b4N

Comment: Thanks! and what if there some other elements like span with the class myspan.. how can I retrieve all of them ? not only the span elements?

Comment: Simply leave off the tag name, which will find all elements with the class: `$("div.myclass .myspan")`

Comment: @ryanbrill In my sample code I looping throw all the div with the class myclass , what I need to is to get the element that has the class myspan from the current(!) div - from your code I'm getting all the span with. this is not what i need! , I want the spans only from the current div

Comment: In that case, you'd probably want something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ryanbrill/Q4b4N/

Comment: @ryanbrill How about putting your updated fiddle code directly in your answer? That would greatly improve it.

Comment: @ErikE Done, though I left the original as well. The way the original question was worded, it was not clear the parent context was needed, so for others stumbling across this answer, they may simply be looking for the original selector.

Comment: @ryanbrill I agree with you... the question was not worded well to explain what was needed.

Answer (score 3):

You con shorten your code as follows

```
 var myspan = $("div.myclass span.myspan ");
```

Comment: Good... but someone beat you. Oh well. :)

Answer (score 2):

If i got you right, then you need [jquery find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) function
something like this code:

```
var spans = $("div.myclass").find('span.myspan');//cache the span
spans.each(function(i,e) {//do what you need
    $(this).addClass('test');//just a sample action
});
```

the same can be achieved with 1 line, like this

```
$("div.myclass").find('span.myspan').addClass('test');
```

but it depends what you want to achieve.
here is a fiddle

Comment: Why use `find` when you can just add it as part of the selector? Is there some performance thing?

Comment: you are right about that, but i'm not sure about which of those is faster?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div.myclass").find(".myspan");
});
```

And if you have only one `div` element, or if you want all of the `span.myspan` elements (even across multiple `div.myclass` elements) in the same collection, you don't need the `.each`.

**UPDATE**

Although `$("div.myclass .myspan")` is valid, `$("div.myclass").find(".myspan")` 
is actually significantly faster!

See this [performance comparison](http://jsperf.com/descend-from-id-vs-select-and-find), which demonstrates `.find` being 93% faster than simply adding the class to the selector!

Comment: Why use `find` when you can just add it as part of the selector? Is there some performance thing?

Comment: @ErikE - Actually, adding it as part of the selector is better for performance. However, based on his implementation I thought that this might be more adaptable, for the reasons noted below my example code. To summarize, putting them in a selector as @ryanbrill and @Sushil did will cause all of the elements to be put in a single collection. My code does as well, but I left it as is, in case he wished to adapt the solution using `.each`, in order to operate on the collections, separately, at different times. In essence, I wanted to introduce him to `.find`.

Comment: I can see that, though in my shabby opinion you should show him the "best" way, *then* educate with other possibilities for different use cases.

Comment: I think that is a fair statement. As the best answer has already been pointed out, I will leave this up for educational purposes, but I will be more conscientious of this going forward.

Comment: In fact, now that the OP explained in more detail what he wants, it seems the `find` syntax is exactly what he needs, since he wants to enumerate over each `div` and do something only with that set of children at a time. So you were on track better than I was! I just like to see explanations for *why* people chose to answer a certain way, since without it the OP is so often left clueless...

Comment: Haha - no worries. I always just try to accommodate. :)

Comment: @ErikE - I was mistaken In saying that `.find` is slower than adding it to the selector. In fact, `.find` is actually 93% faster! I guess I did show him the *best* solution first haha :) See: http://jsperf.com/descend-from-id-vs-select-and-find